# JMeter JSON Extractor to get values as an array

Tags: json, jmeter, extract

I would like to extract variable from a `JSON output` as an array of values. I use `JSON extractor` on `Main samples and sub-samples`. I got two variables, when I check it with a `Debug sampler`: `myvariable` has a single value and `myvariable__matchNr=25`. There are 25 occurences of this variable, so I need all the 25 values too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option `Match No.` in `JSON extractor` has to be -1 to get all the values with variable name: `myvariable_X`.